# Why is my target value not the same when I print it out and calculate it with the coefs and intercept?

Tags: python, machine-learning, polynomials

I have worked on a Polynomial Regression model to predict my target values.
The thing is that my prediction , with the "predict" method, make sense, but when I calculate the target variable via the coefs and intercept I get a value way far from the given values of the predict method.

```
pol = PolynomialFeatures(degree= 9)
    
xp = pol.fit_transform(x_train)
    
poly_reg = LinearRegression()
poly_reg.fit(xp,y_train)
    
poly_test = pol.fit_transform(x_test)
    
pred = poly_reg.predict(poly_test)


poly_reg.predict(pol.fit_transform([[2]]))

Output:
array([[6.07673981]])
```

If I calculate the y value for x = 2 via the coefs and intercept, I obtain a value around 90.

[[ 0.00000000e+00,  4.66507179e+00, -7.69101941e-01 ,-5.47401755e-01,
2.92321976e-01, -5.57600284e-02,  5.44143396e-03, -2.91464609e-04,
8.16565621e-06, -9.36811416e-08]][[0.99640058]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polynomial Transform The value of the variable gets converted in such a way that it fits the linear model.so if the equation is

x^3+x^2+x+c this is the polynomial equation

When you apply polynomial Features it creates values of X such that we can use it in a linear equation so that we can apply the linear model.

So using the linear coefficients with the actual polynomial value of x is going to give a different answer

Comment: So this means in this case that I cannot simply use x as 2 and put in to the linear coefficients, because the value 2 gets converted to fit the model. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Because that is what polynomial feautres is for so you can use linear model for curves with higher powers.

Comment: I still have a question. I printed out my model's coefs via the polyfit and poly1d function. Can I now simply insert my x values in to this function? Because when I do so I again obtain a different y value...

Comment: let's say feature X is related to target y in a cubic fashion. Now polynomial features converts those 3 powers into 3 different linear variables with different values. So for 1 value of X you will get 3 values of imagine 3 features linearly related to y. Then you can use multiple linear regression coefficients or model to get the target value